# Custom div element (polymer) doesn't listen to contentEditable="true"

Tags: dart, contenteditable, dart-polymer

I have the following code. The problem is that I can't edit the content of the div. The div does look like a contenteditable div, but it doesn't work like it. I can't actually edit any of the text. Did I make a mistake somewhere ?

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="kp-test" extends="div">

<template>
Content
</template>

<script type="application/dart">
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:html';

@CustomTag('kp-test')
class KPTest extends DivElement with Polymer, Observable{

  KPTest.created() : super.created() {
    polymerCreated();
  }

  attached() {
    super.attached();
    contentEditable = "true";
    style.color = "red";
  }
}
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Can you please try to add the tag `<content></content>` instead of `Content` (or `<content>Content</content>`). I can't currently try it out myself because pub serve fails every time (http://dartbug.com/22099)

Comment: Alternatively you could insert a `<div contenteditable="true"></div>` (wrapping it instead of extending it) instead of `Content`. In this case you wouldn't need to extend the `DIV` (just create a custom element which doesn't extend any other element).

Comment: `<content></content>` works, but if I add anything else to the template inside or outisde content, the div element seems to kind of freeze, not react anymore. I think your second suggestion is maybe the best way to go indeed, thanks.

Comment: I very seldom extend DOM elements. I also think the 2nd approach is better because it's simpler (beaten path). I'll have a look at the first attempt when my project is up again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you could insert a  (wrapping it instead of extending it) instead of "Content".
In this case you wouldn't need to extend the DIV (just create a custom element which doesn't extend any other element).